# Excel (GoogleSpreadsheet) : I want to match text in a column and alter other columns of the same row

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am creating a spreadsheet to help with inventory and orders. The Inventory table looks like this:

```
Product       Number Sold
Flashlight    some number
Toolbox       some number
```

The Orders table looks like this:

```
Customer      Product      Number Sold
Alice         Flashlight       5
Bob           Flashlight       2
```

I am in search of the proper function to use for accumulating on the inventory list the total number sold for each product in the orders list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a look at my example. Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]